# protobuf.js reflection vs. static code

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I can't figure out when it is better to use the approach of loading .proto files (Reflection) and when it is better to generate static code with the pbjs script/tool.

### Method with Reflection:

```
protobuf.load("awesome.proto", function(err, root) {
   ...
});
```

### Method with Static Code:

```
protobuf.load("bundle.json", function(err, root) {
    ...
});
```

According to the [protobuf.js Wiki](http://dcode.io/protobuf.js/#reflection-vs-static-code), the performance is the same for both approaches.

Can someone explain to me which approach is for which purpose?

I've searched a lot on the internet but was not able to get an answer to this question. I'm not stuck from a coding perspective, rather than to figure out which approach suits better.

Comment: I think this question is too broad... :/

Comment: Well, how should I be more specific? I really can't find an answer to which of both approaches are used when.

Comment: Try to post some code, examples, or something that could make your question more specific. This is not always easy, but we need to know what you have tried and where you are stuck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement on performance is only about the usage of the (de)serialisation functions, not about the setup. From the docs you linked:

## `.proto`

- requires the **full** library
- high number of network requests and parser **overhead**

## `.json`

- requires the **light** library
- bundling is **recommended** for production environments, parsing done ahead of time

## compiled

- Generated static code, works with just the **minimal** library
- generates additional, albeit editable, source code **without any reflection features**.